# VS Code Syntax Highlighting Mistaking Type?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, vs-color-theme-editor

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# INITIAL CONDITIONS
m = 550E03 # kg
r = 3.7 / 2 # m
l = 70 # m

I = m * ( (r ** 2) / 4 + (l ** 2) / 12 ) # kg * m^2

position = [0, 0] # m
velocity = [0, 0] # m/s
acceleration = [0, 0] # m/s^2
theta = np.pi / 2 # rad

F_g = [0, -53.935E06] # N
F_R = [80.905E06 * np.cos(theta), 80.905E06 * np.sin(theta)] # N
```

With this code, VS Code seems to change the color of the variable `F_R` arbitrarily. I've noticed it does the same for any variable named with the format `[Capital Letter]_[Capital Letter]`. Any particular idea why this might be the case, and/or how to change this? It is not dependent on VS Code's Color Theme.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [per PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#constants):

> Constants
>
> Constants are usually defined on a module level and written in all
> capital letters with underscores separating words. Examples include
> `MAX_OVERFLOW` and `TOTAL`.

VSCode considers `F_R` constant and that's why the color is different. You can confirm if hoover with mouse over it.

As a side note, with my setup of VSCode, all other variables/names are light-blue and `pylint` complains they don't conform to naming convention for constants.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by buran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73839894/) already explains why the colors are different. Here's a way to modify the color.

***vscode syntax highlighting is related to the theme.***

[image]
*Theme: [Abyss]*

[image]
*Theme: [Dark High Contrast]*

You can customize syntax highlighting in `settings.json` with the following configuration

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Default Dark+]": {
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                    "scope": "variable.other.constant",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#FF0000"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

[image]
*Theme: [Default Dark+]*